# How to lambdify an Intersection

Tags: python, sympy, set-intersection, lambdify

I am inverting a function with the `invert_real` from `sympy.solvers.solveset`, because neither `solve` nor `solveset` can do it for some reason. The result is an `Intersection` and seems to be correct.

I now want to use it for numeric calculations. When I try it with `.subs` it works fine, but when I try to `lambdify` I get

> NameError: name 'Intersection' is not defined

I already found that I need to pass a source for `Intersection` in the `modules=` of `lambdify`. But I can't find a working source.

Here is a code example:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers.solveset import invert_real

x, y = symbols('x,y')

expr = 1 - exp(-18000000*x)

res_alg = invert_real(expr, y, x)[1]
print("res_alg: ", res_alg)

res_1 = res_alg.subs(y, 0.5)
print("res_1: ", res_1)

res = lambdify(y, res_alg, "numpy")
print(res, res(0.5))
```

Comment: I posted an [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14300) regarding the performance of solve and solveset on this equation.

Comment: @FTP That thread has some interesting info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to ignore Intersection and lambdify only the set that is its second argument.

```
res = lambdify(y, next(iter(res_alg.args[1])), "numpy")
print(res(0.5))
```

Prints `3.850817669777474e-08`.

Here, `res_alg.args` is the list of arguments of Intersection. args[1] picks {-log(-y + 1)/18000000}. `next(iter(...))` picks the first element from that set, so that the lambdified function returns a float instead of a set.

If you pass a value for which there is no real solution, such as `res(1.5)`, the output is nan.